# Add PodMonitor or ServiceMonitor outside of kube-prometheus-stack helm values

Tags: prometheus-operator, kube-prometheus-stack, servicemonitor

Using [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart, version 35.2.0. So far, I add my custom `PrometheusRules`, `PodMonitor` and `ServiceMonitor` via helm custom values.

```bash
helm install my-kubpromstack prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring \
  -f my-AlertRules.yaml \
  -f my-PodMonitor.yaml
```

Or in case of changes in the `PrometheusRules` or `PodMonitor`, I use `helm upgrade`. The custom values are defined based on [kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml). Where I define `prometheus.additionalPodMonitors` and `additionalPrometheusRulesMap` in separate YAML files

```bash
helm upgrade my-kubpromstack -n monitoring \
  --reuse-values \
  -f my-AlertRules.yaml \
  -f my-PodMonitor.yaml
```

**QUESTION**: how to make the Prometheus server from `kube-prometheus-stack` aware of rules, podmonitor, servicemonitor created outside of the helm values?

For example, the `PodMonitor` definition below is NOT picked-up by Prometheus (ie doesn't appear in the targets in Prometheus UI).

```yaml
kubectl apply -f - << EOF
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: cluster-operator-metrics
  labels:
    app: strimzi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - my-strimzi
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: http
EOF
```

The pod to monitor has a label `strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator` and is located in `my-strimzi` namespace. I would expect the `podmonitor` above to be recognized by Prometheus automatically. Because the default [podMonitorSelector: {}](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2071) in kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml has a comment that says:

```
    ## PodMonitors to be selected for target discovery.
    ## If {}, select all PodMonitors
```

**EDIT**: Looks like this question is useful to quite some people. The simplest solution is what Aris Chow suggested below. Set the custom helm values as below:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    probeSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the repository link if you got it working? I have been stuck for almost two weeks for same issue - Strimzi Metrics in Prometheus using kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.

Comment: Sorry private project. However I added an additional answer below to show a working example. Good lucks

Comment: No worries, @aris's answer helped me to resolve it after 15mins of commenting for repository. BTW I have implemented and pushed in to the [repository](https://github.com/waqasdilawar/strimzi-kafka-k8s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define `prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUseHelmValues` as `false` (in `values.yaml`, it is set to `true` by default) you could achieve your goal. As the value is `true`, it would just try to set a `release` label for matching `PodMonitor`, which your own definition does not include.

Or, you could leave it as `true` and set `prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelector` as:

```
matchLabels:
  prometheus: "true"
```

And add label `prometheus: "true"` in your `podmonitor.yaml`.

Click [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/kube-prometheus-stack-15.4.4/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L127-L136) to check the code if you are intereseted in details.

Please note that the chart version in this link is `15.4.4`, you should change to the version you are using just in case there are any update.

Comment: Expert answer thanks. Will confirm when I resume working on this project next week. I assume the comment in [kube-prometheus-stack/values.yam, podMonitorSelector](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blame/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2075) is incorrect.

Comment: Confirmed your suggestion is working. Thanks very much. Same principle for `PrometheusRule` by setting a custom label for `prometheus.prometheusSpec.ruleSelector.matchLabels`

Comment: @Polymerase Yes I think some of the comments in the values.yaml is a little bit out of date - read the logic in template files instead if necessary :-)

Answer (score 4):

Add this answer to address the question asked by a commenter in OP. Here is the PodMonitor definition I used + the custom helm values for the `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart to have Prometheus operator discover the pod as target. The main point is the label `app: strimzi`. The comment section show how to configure helm to make Prometheus recognize that label.

```json
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The kube-prometheus-stack helm chart must have the value
# podMonitorSelector.matchLabels set to match the label `app: strimzi` of the PodMonitors below.
# Otherwise Prometheus operator will not scrape the metrics of the corresponding pods
#
# prometheus:
#   prometheusSpec:
#     podMonitorSelector:
#       matchLabels:
#         app: strimzi
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: strimzi-cluster-operator-metrics
  labels:
    app: strimzi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - strimzi
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: http
```